# LinkedIn Share Button - Doesn't recognize og:image

Tags: image, share, linkedin-api

I'm trying to share a page with og tags.
One of the tags is og:image as described in the following link:
https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/setting-display-tags-shares
The image I share is legal.

For some reason linkedin doesn't show the image once I'm sharing the page through 
LinkedIn Share button (although it shows the other tags' values).

My og:image tag:

meta property="og:image" content="http://mywebsite.comm/difa2fz.png"

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Please visit http://ogp.me/ and apply all the mandatory tags. 4 tags are mandatory others are optional. Also you need to mention the schema og: http://ogp.me/ns# in the HTML tag of page as prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I have added all og:image tags.LinkedIn takes 3 images on sharing and one among this is og:image I have specified and other two random images from the page.How can I restrict LinkedIn to take the sibngle og:image I have specified

Answer (score 0):

According to the **[Official LinkedIn OG Tags Sharing Documentation](https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/46687/making-your-website-shareable-on-linkedin?lang=en)**, the following are required for the `og:image`...

- Max file size: 5 MB
- Minimum image dimensions: 1200 (w) x 627 (h) pixels
- Recommended ratio: 1.91:1

Have doubts about your link?  You can submit your share URL to the **[LinkedIn Post Inspector](https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/)**, which will analyze, debug, and explain any problems you have in your share URL, including `og` tag issues.

You provided us with your code, but not the image, so, you'll need to make sure your image conforms to the above limits.  In addition, since I can't see *all the code*, I'd also add in the following informal requirements...

- Is your `og:image` tag in the `<header>...</header>` block of your HTML?
- Does your page have a `<html>...</html>` block?

Here's a demo site I host where the LinkedIn share URL works.  This is purely a demo site, and it has no monetary value (its stated purpose is to "sort words").  [SortWords.com](http://www.sortwords.com/), and the share URL is: [https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.sortwords.com](http://Share%20SortWords.com%20on%20LinkedIn).  Works great:

[image]