# Sharing on Linkedin does not always pull og:image

Tags: html, linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph

When sharing articles on Linkedin, sometimes the image specified in the og:image tag gets displayed, sometimes it doesn't.

Here is an example where it works: https://newsroom.porsche.com/en/history/porsche-history-litera-tour-erfurt-weimar-944-turbo-cabriolet-13865.html

And a not working example: https://newsroom.porsche.com/en/company/porsche-half-year-2017-increase-operating-result-revenue-deliveries-employees-14005.html

All relevant og:tags are present (besides the one at the html tag, but as shown above, it is not needed) as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12018064/linkedin-share-button-doesnt-recognize-ogimage).

What I did find out though: In the working example, the image is stored within Amazon S3 while it is stored directly on the server in the non-working example. Sorry for not posting the links to the images directly but my reputation does allow for only two links per post.

Other than that are both links valid, both images are the same size and the server does not have any geo restrictions. Both pages are using the same template, so I figure it can't be the markup either.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it is `Content-type: image/jpeg` header that is missing on a response for image stored on a server.